# Continue ‘for’ loop with the existing variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging, for-loop

I have a Matlab script including a `for` loop which loos like the following:

```
for k = 1:10
    c = myfun(k,a,b);
    result{k} = c;
end
```

Right now, the problem is that during the `for` loop, sometimes `myfun()` may have errors and stop. After fixing the error in `myfun()`, how can I continue to run with the existing value of variables? The reason is that `myfun()` will take a very long time to get the result and the previous results are right.

For example, if a error happens when `k == 4`, then I save all the variables in the current workspace. I set a breakpoint at `c = myfun(k,a,b);` and restore the saved variables, but I find that in the next loop, `k` will be `2` instead of `5` as I want. Matlab is not allowed to modify the value of k during the for loop I think. I have tested this for a few times.

How can I continue the `for` loop with some existing data?

Comment: Maybe initialize your dataset with the data you've already computed, and just start the loop at whichever iteration is next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change your `for` loop iterator programmatically inside of the loop.

For example:

```
for ii = 1:3
    disp(ii)
    ii = 3;
end
```

Prints:

```
 1

 2

 3
```

If you're going to be modifying code based on errors received, [`dbstop if error`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) is not going to be beneficial because it will not reflect changes in your code until the debugger is exited and your code executed again (unless you execute manually in the debugger). If you're not modifying code you could potentially use a [`try/except`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) clause to catch fixable issues.

If you're loading data for a later index and then restarting, you can change where your `for` loop begins, or use a `while` loop (if appropriate).

For example:

```
% Load data here
for ii = 3:3
    disp(ii)
end
```

Prints `3`.

Where the `while` interpretation would be:

```
% Load data here
ii = 3
while ii <= 3
    disp(ii)
    ii = ii + 1;
end
```

For the same result.

Comment: For the `while` loop, it is still not allowed to change the loop variable `ii`? I did not check that.

Comment: You can change the loop variable inside a `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

On solution can be first catch the exception likes the following and pass from them:

```
bug = [];
for k = 1:10
    try
        c = myfun(k,a,b);
        result{k} = c;
    catch
        warning('some bug for the following values:');
        display([k a b]);
        bug = [bug; k a b];
        result{k} = NaN;
    end
end
```

Then iterate over `bug` to compute missing information after debugging. This solution works when your algorithm is not dependent on the previous value of the result (or is not recursive).